# SQL NOT IN failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that will check the temp table if there is a record that do not exist on the main table. My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].[PDCampaignBatch_temp]
WHERE [StartDateTime] NOT IN (SELECT [StartDateTime] FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].PDCampaignBatch GROUP BY [StartDateTime])
```

but the problem is it does not display this row

[image]

even if that data does not exist in my main table. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You could try `EXCEPT`. It's literally what you want if you're looking for all rows except those already in the main table (assuming you match by all columns, not merely `StartDateTime`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert fucking hell, you're a life saver. Post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT IN` has strange semantics.  If any values in the subquery are `NULL`, then the query returns no rows at all.  For this reason, I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].[PDCampaignBatch_temp] t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].PDCampaignBatch cb
                  WHERE t.StartDateTime = cb.StartDateTime
                 );
```

Answer (score 3):

If the set is evaluated by the SQL *NOT IN* condition contains any values that are null, then the outer query here will return an empty set, even if there are many [*StartDateTime*]s that match [*StartDateTime*]s in the *PDCampaignBatch* table.

To avoid such issue,

```
SELECT *
FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].[PDCampaignBatch_temp]
WHERE [StartDateTime] NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [StartDateTime]
        FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].PDCampaignBatch
        WHERE [StartDateTime] IS NOT NULL
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `PDCampaignBatch_temp` and `PDCampaignBatch` happen to have the same structure (same columns in the same order) and you're tasked with getting the set of all rows in `PDCampaignBatch_temp` that aren't in `PDCampaignBatch`. The most effective way to do that is to make use of the [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) operator, which will deal with `NULL` in the expected way as well:

```
SELECT * FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].[PDCampaignBatch_temp]
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM [Telemarketing].[dbo].[PDCampaignBatch]
```

In production code that is not a one-off, don't use `SELECT *`, write out the column names instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your issue is with the datetime.  You may be only displaying a certain degree of percision like the year/month/date.  The data may be stored as year/month/date/hour/minute/second/milisecond.  If so you have to match down the the most granluar measurement of the data.  If one field is a date and the other is a date time they also will likely never match up.  Thus you always get no responses.